# How create an instance which depends on a database context in ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Hello StackOverflow people,

I need an instance of a class which is dependent on a database context service, e.g.

```
            services.AddScoped<IAccountCreationService, AccountCreationService>();
            var _accountCreationService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IAccountCreationService>();

            services
                .AddAuthentication(options => {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                }).AddCookie(options => {
                    options.Events = new Authentication.CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents {
                        accountCreationService = _accountCreationService,
                    };
                })
```

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Zukte.Database;
using Zukte.Message.ApplicationUser;

namespace Zukte.Utilities.Account {
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public class AccountCreationService : IAccountCreationService {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext databaseService;

        public AccountCreationService(ApplicationDbContext databaseService) {
            this.databaseService = databaseService;
        }

        public async Task<ApplicationUser> PostApplicationUser(ApplicationUser applicationUser) {
        }
    }
}
```

When using the `BuildServiceProvider()` approach I run into the following error:

```
The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

because the "injected" database service into AccountCreationService is not disposed of like usual. Additionally, if I use this alternative approach:

```
            IAccountCreationService? accountCreator = null;
            services.AddScoped<IAccountCreationService>(serviceProvider => {
                var databaseService = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>() ??
                    throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(ApplicationDbContext));

                accountCreator = new AccountCreationService(databaseService);
                return accountCreator;
            });
```

then either `accountCreationService` will be null or I run into the following error:

```
Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'ApplicationDbContext'.
```

because the "injected" database service into AccountCreationService is disposed of.

How can work around this or solve this problem? I want to be able to persist an account to the database after the user signs in.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not resolving the `IAccountCreationService` in the event handlers themselves?

Comment: Looking at [this page in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0#react-to-back-end-changes), you can just register `CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents` in the `services` as scoped and then just set the `EventsType` property: `options.EventsType = typeof(Authentication.CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [devNull's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5803406/devnull) comment I was able to solve this problem.

Using this approach, you can use DI in the AddCookie method:

```
                ).AddCookie(options => {
                    options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
```

Comment: Also, all MS services follow the options pattern, so you can perform further configuration in an `IConfigureOptions<T>` service.